# How to read and print a unicode file

Tags: c, unicode

I have a test input file `input.txt` with one line with the following contents:

```
кёльнский
```

I am using this code to attempt to read it in and print it out.

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *input;
    wchar_t buf[1000];

    setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"");   

    if ((input = fopen("input.txt","r")) == NULL)
         return 1;

    printf("Read and print\n");
    while (fgetws(buf,1000,input)!=NULL)
        wprintf(L"%s",buf);

    fclose(input);
}
```

However when I run it I see "Read and print" and then nothing else.

I am compiling with gcc on Ubuntu.

What am I doing wrong?

---

It turns out that substituting the wprintf line with

```
printf("%ls",buf);
```

fixes the problem.

Why is this?

Comment: Check file encoding. Is it UTF-16 or UTF-8?

Comment: You should try to figure out why `fgetws` is returning `NULL` (assuming that's what is happening).  Use `feof` or `ferror` to see if it was an error or an end-of-file, and if it was an error, examine `errno` to see what the error was. (Use of `perror` is highly recommended.)

Comment: Start by turning on compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` is a good start).

Comment: @Joshua It is UTF-8

Comment: @Shawn No warnings. Did you get some?

Comment: You should because you're using the wrong printf format for a wide string.

Comment: We can’t tell you the correct encoding without seeing (a representative, ideally small sample of) the actual contents of the data in an unambiguous representation; a hex dump of the problematic byte(s) with a few bytes of context on each side is often enough, especially if you can tell us what you think those bytes are supposed to represent. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: Personally I'd just use `fputws()` here. `wprintf()` is overkill.

Comment: @tripleee od input.txt 
0000000 135320 110721 135720 106321 136720 100721 135320 134320
0000020 134720 000012
0000023

Comment: Octal is a lot less readable and familiar than hex for many readers. Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing two things wrong:

1. Mixing normal (byte-oriented) and wide output functions to standard output. You need to stick to one or the other. From the C11 draft, section 7.21.2:

> Each stream has an orientation. After a stream is associated with an external file, but before any operations are performed on it, the stream is without orientation. Once a wide character input/output function has been applied to a stream without orientation, the stream becomes a wide-oriented stream. Similarly, once a byte input/output function has been applied to a stream without orientation, the stream becomes a byte-oriented stream. ...

> Byte input/output functions shall not be applied to a wide-oriented stream and wide character input/output functions shall not be applied to a byte-oriented stream.

2. Using the wrong printf format to print a wide string. `%s` is for a normal `char` string. `%ls` is for a `wchar_t` string. But for just printing a wide string to a wide stream, prefer `fputws()`. No point in using a printf function if you're not actually using its formatting capabilities or mixing literal text with variables or printing wide characters to a byte-oriented stream or something else fancy.

One way (Of many alternatives) to fix the above problems, that treats standard output as a wide-oriented stream:

```c
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *input;
    wchar_t buf[1000];

    setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"");   

    if ((input = fopen("input.txt","r")) == NULL)
         return 1;

    fputws(L"Read and print\n", stdout);
    while (fgetws(buf,1000,input)!=NULL)
        fputws(buf, stdout);

    fclose(input);
}
```

Another, using a byte-oriented standard output:

```c
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *input;
    wchar_t buf[1000];

    setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"");

    if ((input = fopen("input.txt","r")) == NULL)
         return 1;

    puts("Read and print");
    while (fgetws(buf,1000,input)!=NULL)
      printf("%ls", buf);

    fclose(input);
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful.  What warning does clang give you? I tried with version 10 and don't get a warning.

Comment: @Anush `foo.c:17:21: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'wchar_t *' (aka 'int *') [-Wformat]`

Comment: 10, though 8 gives the same warning.

Comment: Strange. I definitely don't get any warnings with clang -Wall -Wextra .  One more thing, if I just want to print a single character from this input, is there a way to do it with putc or equivalent?

Comment: @Anush If printing to a wide stream, you can use `fputwc()` or friends. For printing to a narrow stream, you have to convert the wide character to a multibyte sequence first with `wcrtomb()`, or store the wide character in a `wint_t` and use the `%lc` printf format.

Answer (score 0):

`fgetws` reads UTF-16. We normally handle UTF-8 with normal `fgets` into `char []` and expect it to work and print it with normal `printf`. That's the point of UTF-8. If it doesn't work on display, probably your terminal isn't UTF-8; this is easily checked by running `cat input.txt`.

Comment: cat input.txt works fine. The input file is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Then doing what this answer says should also work. Are you saying it doesn't?

Comment: Wide I/o functions convert between a locale-determined encoding and a system-dependent wide encoding. The file doesn't need to be a Unicode one. Neither do wide chars (though they're commonly utf-32 or utf-16 or maybe even ucs-2)